# Uniform convergence a.e.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $$f_n,\ f:\mathbb (\Omega,\mathcal A, \mathcal m) \to (\mathbb R, \mathcal L, \lambda)$$
Be a measurable function.
I have to prove that if $f_n$ converges uniformly a.e. to $f$ then $f_n$ converges pointwise a.e. to $f$, which means
$$ess \sup \ |f_n-f|\to 0\ \implies $$
$$ \forall x\in\Omega_h, \ \mathcal(\Omega_h^c)=0\ \ |f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$$
(For the meaning of $ess \sup$ see the reference at the bottom).\
My idea (which is much simpler that the one I found in my book, and so it could be wrong) is:
Let $e_k\to 0$ be a sequence of positive numbers
$$ess \sup |f_n-f| \to 0$$
implies by definition
\begin{equation}\forall k \ \exists \Omega_k \ \exists N\ \forall n>N\ \forall x\in \Omega_k \end{equation}

$$ |f_n(x)-f(x)|<e_k,\ \mathcal m(\Omega_k ^c)=0$$
Now choose 
$$\Omega_h=\cap_k \Omega_k$$
Then
$$\mathcal m(\Omega_h)≥1-\sum _k \mathcal m(\Omega_k^c)=1$$
And
$$\forall x\in \Omega_h \ f_n(x)\to f(x)$$

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum

Comment: Is $m$ supposed to be a probability measure?

Comment: To get ride of finiteness assumptions of the measure, you can just write $$ m(\Omega_h^c) = m(\Omega \setminus \bigcap_{k} \Omega_k) = m(\bigcup_k \Omega_k^c) \leq \sum_k m (\Omega_k^c) =0. $$

Comment: where comes the $1$ in this expression $\mathcal m(\Omega_h)≥1-\sum _k \mathcal m(\Omega_k^c)=1$? It is $\Omega$ a probability space, maybe?